# $G_{\delta}$ set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I have a homework as follows:

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover of $X$.If $\mathcal{V}$ is finite subset of $\mathcal{U}$ but $\mathcal{V}$ doesn't cover $X$, prove that $X-\bigcup\mathcal{V}$ is a closed $G_{\delta}$ set.

I know that $X-\bigcup\mathcal{V}$ is closed. But I still confuse why it is a $G_{\delta}$ set.

Please help me to prove it

Comment: What assumptions on $X$? Metric? It cannot be true in general.